# Issue with “Unable to access address of buffer” MInecraft 1.10.2 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, launcher, minecraft

I have scoured the web for an answer to this problem. And I keep coming up with this vague as all else answer:

> For reference for anyone else having this issue, go to edit profile. In the executable box, put the path to java. (For me, it was `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java` check which version you're using) In JVM arguments, I had `-Xmx2560M -Xms512M.`

It doesn't really explain what needs to be specifically done, other than just check that the destinations are correct. No matter how much I ensure that the destination is correct, alter the -Xmx exceptions for the memory limits, or alter any of the other exceptions it still gives me the same Unable to access address of buffer problem.

Do I have too much memory allocated, too little, something else is potentially set up poorly within my laptop? Furthermore I would love to have just commented on the original post or message the person that posted the "answer," but it won't let me.

Here is what I can provide in terms of basic information that I believe is relevant.

1. This is my executable location: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle/bin/java`
2. This is the only thing I have in java exception field `-Xmx2560M -Xms512M`
3. I am able to start up my own world as much and for however long I please.
4. The Minecraft launcher title goes from *Minecraft Launcher* during start up to *Minecraft Launcher null* after the launcher has finished its initial startup.

That's all I got for info, any of you got ideas? I'm sorry if there is a definitive answer for this, but I have checked out so very many places, and come up with absolutely no solution to my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you until I downgrade Java to version 8. And that did solve my problem. In Ubuntu I install "oracle-java8-installer" and check path and JVM arguments that it was as described above.

Comment: That did it. I appreciate the help!